# Getting "winrm send_input failed" when using os_server module and local connection

Tags: ansible, openstack, winrm

I'm trying to write a playbook for a Windows VM that also creates the VM with the `os_server` module.
I'm starting with a simple `win_ping`, given the VM is already there:

```
- name: Create instance
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Ping machine
      win_ping:
```

running it with `ansible-playbook site.yml --inventory=10.204.0.9,`
results in:

```
PLAY [Create instance] ************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ************************************************************************
ok: [10.204.0.9]

TASK [Ping machine] ***************************************************************************
ok: [10.204.0.9]

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
10.204.0.9                 : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Now I add the `os_server` task:

```
- name: Create Windows Instance
  connection: local
  os_server:
    state: present
    region_name: "{{ os_region_name }}"
    auth: "{{ cloud.auth }}"
    name: "windows-{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    image: Windows 2012 R2 Datacenter
    key_name: vector_ops
    flavor: 1C-2GB-50GB
    floating_ips:
      - "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
- name: Ping machine
  win_ping:
```

I'm setting `connection` to `local` as I want this task to be executed from the control machine, in case the VM is not created yet.

When I run this playbook again with `ansible-playbook site.yml --inventory=10.204.0.9,`, I get:

```
TASK [Create Windows Instance] ****************************************************************
 [WARNING]: FATAL ERROR DURING FILE TRANSFER: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/winrm.py", line 276, in
_winrm_exec     self._winrm_send_input(self.protocol, self.shell_id, command_id, data,
eof=is_last)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/winrm.py",
line 256, in _winrm_send_input     protocol.send_message(xmltodict.unparse(rq))   File
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 207, in send_message
return self.transport.send_message(message)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/winrm/transport.py", line 202, in send_message     raise WinRMTransportError('http',
error_message) WinRMTransportError: (u'http', u'Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code
500')

fatal: [10.204.0.9]: FAILED! => {"msg": "winrm send_input failed"}
```

I'm a bit puzzled why there is an error during a file transfer, so I ran the command with `-vvv`:

```
TASK [Create Windows Instance] ****************************************************************
task path: /home/ubuntu/basic-windows-example/trunk/playbooks/site.yml:8
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/cloud/openstack/os_server.py
<10.204.0.9> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: Admin on PORT 5986 TO 10.204.0.9
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
```

And indeed it seems so that Ansible tries to establish a winrm connection, despite `connection: local`. Removing `connection: local` from the task brings the same result as above.
I would expect the task to return a simple "ok" since the VM is already there.
What am I missing here?

**Update 2018-01-09, 9:45 GMT:**

So I tried another experiment: I removed all `ansible_*` variables from the var file (see below) just to see what Ansible does with the `os_server` task when no WinRM connection is configured. Running it again with `ansible-playbook site.yml --inventory=10.204.0.9, -vvv` this time I get for the `os_server` task:

```
TASK [Create Windows Instance] ****************************************************************
task path: /home/ubuntu/basic-windows-example/trunk/playbooks/site.yml:9
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/cloud/openstack/os_server.py
<10.204.0.9> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: ubuntu
<10.204.0.9> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~ && sleep 0'
<10.204.0.9> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1515490597.4-208015762064624 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1515490597.4-208015762064624="` echo /home/ubuntu/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1515490597.4-208015762064624 `" ) && sleep 0'
<rest cut off for brevity>
```

So now a local connection does get established and the `os_server` task completes successfully. But of course, this is not the answer, because I need the WinRM connection configured for the Windows VM.

**Update 2018-01-09, 10:00 GMT:**

Following the suggestion to add `gather_facts: false` to the play and running `ansible-playbook site.yml --inventory=10.204.0.9,`, I now get:

```
PLAY [Create instance] ************************************************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [Create Windows Instance] ****************************************************************
task path: /home/ubuntu/basic-windows-example/trunk/playbooks/site.yml:10
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/cloud/openstack/os_server.py
<10.204.0.9> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: Admin on PORT 5986 TO 10.204.0.9
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
 [WARNING]: FATAL ERROR DURING FILE TRANSFER: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/winrm.py", line 276, in
_winrm_exec     self._winrm_send_input(self.protocol, self.shell_id, command_id, data,
eof=is_last)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/plugins/connection/winrm.py",
line 256, in _winrm_send_input     protocol.send_message(xmltodict.unparse(rq))   File
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/winrm/protocol.py", line 207, in send_message
return self.transport.send_message(message)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/winrm/transport.py", line 202, in send_message     raise WinRMTransportError('http',
error_message) WinRMTransportError: (u'http', u'Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code
500')

fatal: [10.204.0.9]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "winrm send_input failed"
}
```

The error is the same, Ansible still tries to establish a WinRM connection.

Full Playbook (site.yml, added `gather_facts: false`):

```
- name: Create instance
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Create Windows Instance
      connection: local
      os_server:
        state: present
        region_name: Region1
        auth: "{{ cloud.auth }}"
        name: "windows-{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        image: Windows 2012 R2 Datacenter
        key_name: mykey
        flavor: 1C-2GB-50GB
        floating_ips:
          - "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    - name: Ping machine
      win_ping:
```

Vars in group_vars/all (used throughout all examples):

```
cloud:
  auth:
    auth_url: https://cloud.internal:5000/v3/
    domain_name: Domain_01
    password: mypassword
    project_name: dev-project
    username: apiuser
os_region_name: Fra1
ansible_user: Admin
ansible_port: 5986
ansible_password: myvmpassword
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
```

Version info:

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.4.2.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/ubuntu/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.12 (default, Nov 20 2017, 18:23:56) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

Comment: You are aware that [deleting a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48153820/2947502) to avoid downvotes and reposting is generally frowned upon and also has [its downsides](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338435/2947502), right?

Comment: Tried gather_facts: false. I thought it best to delete my original question and restart from scratch. It was not my intention to avoid downvotes. Also, can I it be that frowned upon if it is "rewarded" with a badge? Genuine question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use `delegate_to: localhost` instead of `connection: local` for the `os_server` task, a local connection does get established. `delegate_to` avoids loading the WinRM connection variables for that connection.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is facing the same issue with Ansible then check the WinRM memory setting on the host and ensure it has sufficient memory.

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 1024
```

Comment: I get the error and have a silly large memory configured.  Just have no idea how to understand cause and fix.  Very frustrating...